# Unnecessary Rerender of whole component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have my React app defined as such:

```
function App() {

  const [clickedNode, setClickedNode] = useState({});
  const [hoveredLink, setHoveredLink] = useState({});

  const updateNode = useCallback((node) => { setClickedNode(node); });

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
    <Col sm={8} >
      <MemoGraph setClickedNode={updateNode} />
    </Col>
    <Col sm={4}>
      <InfoSection node={clickedNode}
        link={hoveredLink} />
    </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container >
  );
}
```

in `MemoGraph`, there is a callback in a graph vizualization that updates the `ClickedNode` state variable.

This is really just to rerender the `InfoSection` object, but it causes the whole component to rerender.

The `MemoGraph` reRendering is really expensive, and needs to stop. In DevTools, the App is said to rerender because of the Hooks changing, which I do not understand. Is there someone that can explain the best way to change parent state in a child component, but so only `InfoSection` renders?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You can wrap `MemoGraph` in `React.memo()`

Comment: I have done this, and it does not seem to help; `export const MemoGraph = React.memo(VisualisationGraph);`

Comment: Can you add `VisualisationGraph` code to your post?

Comment: We can help if you can create a minimal code example to reproduce the issue in a codesandbox?